# Exchange 2010 Offline Address Book replication/distribution schedule?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I've just added a few conference rooms to an Exchange 2010 site. I'm curious as to how and when the OAB get updated. For instance, when would I be able to see it via my Macintosh's Outlook 2011? What is the distribution schedule to regular Windows Outlook clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many moving parts, but the two major areas to this:

1st step is server (default once a day I believe) will create the Offline Address Book files and store in https URL for 2007 and 2010/2011 clients. walkthough http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/offline-address-book-part1.html

2nd the Outlook client (if in cached mode) checks for new OAB files via https URL. Not sure of it's schedule but it's likely once a day by default as well. Outlook OAB control on Windows http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823580

Answer (score 1):

The default OAB server update kicks off at 5am.  Depending on how large your Address Book is it can take a few hours to finish updating.

Answer (score 1):

@ewwhite: I stumbled over a comparable issue today (Outlook 2011 and rooms): The Mac Outlook 2011 uses LDAP, the OAB is not of interest in that case. Thus, once you've set up the rooms and they are listed in the AD, your Outlook 2011 can query them if your Outlook 2011 is set up to query the proper LDAP server/root-DN.

Comment: Oddly enough, it looks like the Mac client can query LDAP, if configured, as well as the Exchange OAB URL.

Comment: It can query the OAB? All I got to work in that case was the directory service/LDAP. Are there some 'less documented' settings (com.microsoft..) you'd like to share?